# "unsupported exec option: close_others" error when starting JRuby

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler, jruby

When running Rake tasks via Bundler 1.10.6 w/ JRuby 9.0.4.0, I receive the following warning:

```
uri:classloader:/jruby/kernel/kernel.rb:17: warning: unsupported exec option: close_others
```

I do not see the same issue when running rake tasks without using `bundle exec`.

Could anyone point me to the source of this warning, or a means to eliminate it?

Answer (score 1):

JRuby 9.X has [changed the way it handles spawning processes](https://developer.zendesk.com/blog/ruby-2-0-changes-exec-bundler).

Starting with v1.4.0.rc1 version of Bundler, there is now an option to bundle exec called --keep-file-descriptors which ports Ruby 1.9's behavior and keeps all relevant file descriptors.  That allows you to suppress this issue.  An alternative approach is to use binstubs.  Upgrading from bundler 1.10.6 to 1.11 also resolves this issue.

For more information, see the [original Bundler issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2628) and the [pull request that added the option](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/2629).